# == or ===, which one should I use to compare two objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, compare, equals, compareobject

I do not mean deep comparison.
I just want to know if two variables refer to the same instance. Should I use `a==b` or `a===b`? Can two variables point to the same memory but with different types? Because javascript has no such concept as class in C++, I do not know what an object's type is. Do all objects have the same type: "object" so === decides their types are equal? If so, === would be the same as ==.

Comment: `Can two variables point to the same memory but with different types?` No. A variable at any given time refers to a specific value with a specific type.

Comment: The duplicate is wrong. This is a different question. I'm sure there's a dupe somewhere but the one linked is not very relevant in the context of this question.

Comment: Though the question likely is a duplicate, the linked question is not an answer to this one, in my opinion.

Comment: Just to add something to the boilerplate, I always reference this on such kind of questions: [Always use 3 equals unless you have a good reason to use 2](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/?utm_content=buffer4f1b9).

Answer (score 1):

From [A Drip of Javascript: Object Equality in Javascript](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html):

> ... Primitives like strings and numbers are compared by their value, while objects like arrays, dates, and **plain objects are compared by their reference**. That comparison by reference basically checks to see if the objects given refer to the same location in memory. Here is an example of how that works.

```js
var jangoFett = {
    occupation: "Bounty Hunter",
    genetics: "superb"
};

var bobaFett = {
    occupation: "Bounty Hunter",
    genetics: "superb"
};

var callMeJango = jangoFett;

// Outputs: false
console.log(bobaFett === jangoFett);

// Outputs: true
console.log(callMeJango === jangoFett);
```

Answer (score -2):

you should use === because it will avoid error exceptions hard to be found. and about time consuming, === is better as well.

Comment: *and about time complexity === is better as well* ... because ?

Comment: i mean time consuming, because it just have to compare value and type. while == will have to parse to all types and compare